# Encrypt files, copy directory tree and those files and copy all to another destination

Tags: python, encryption, copy, shutil, os.path

This is what I have:

```
bufferSize = 64 * 1024
password1 = 'password'

def copyDirectoryTree(source, dest, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    if not os.path.exists(dest):
        os.makedirs(dest)
    for item in os.listdir(source):
        pathOrigen = os.path.join(source, item)
        pathDest = os.path.join(dest, item)
        if os.path.isdir(pathSource):
            copiarArbolDirectorios(pathSource, pathDest, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(pathDest) or os.stat(pathSource).st_mtime - 
os.stat(pathDest).st_mtime > 1:
            shutil.copy2(pathSource, pathDest)

copyDirectoryTree(sourcePath, destinationPath)

############# Encryptation #############
for archivo in glob.glob(destinationPath + '//**/*', recursive=True):
    fullPath = archivo
    fullNuevoFichero = archivo + '.aes'
    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
        print('>>> Original: \t' + fullPath + '')
        print('>>> Encriptado: \t' + fullNuevoFichero + '\n')
        pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(fullPath, fullNuevoFichero, password1, bufferSize)
        os.remove(fullPath)
```

The code first copies tree with files and everything and then encrypts files and deletes the ones with extension different from .aes, but I would like to copy only files with extension .aes, this is, encrypt before copying, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: what is the problem to run code in different order - first code which encrypt and next code which copy folders and files with extension .aes ?

Comment: I already tried that before opening the question and if I change order it doesn't encrypt, it just copies directory tree and files.

Comment: did you change pathes. You have to use source path instead of destination path. You could also simpy use `print()` to check values in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Now it moves files when they are encrypted.

```
bufferSize = 64 * 1024
password1 = 'password'

def copyDirectoryTree(source, dest, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    if not os.path.exists(dest):
        os.makedirs(dest)
    for item in os.listdir(source):
        pathOrigen = os.path.join(source, item)
        pathDestino = os.path.join(dest, item)
        if os.path.isdir(pathSource):
            copiarArbolDirectorios(pathAource, pathDest, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(pathDest) or os.stat(pathsource).st_mtime - os.stat(pathDest).st_mtime > 1:
                if item.endswith('.aes'):
                    shutil.copy2(path>ource, pathDest)

############# Encryptation #############
for archivo in glob.glob(sourcePath + '//**/*', recursive=True):
    fullPath = archivo
    fullNuevoFichero = archivo + '.aes'
    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
        print('>>> Original: \t' + fullPath + '')
        print('>>> Encriptado: \t' + fullNuevoFichero + '\n')
        pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(fullPath, fullNuevoFichero, password1, bufferSize)
        copiarArbolDirectorios(sourcePath, destinationPath)
        os.remove(fullNuevoFichero)
```